# How to avoid table overflow (overlap) another side?

Tags: tables, tabularx

How to make the content below as 2 rows instead of 1 row?

I want to make it to

`Selecting
Panel`
(2 row) instead of `Selecting Panel` (1 row)

The reason is this is a 2 column page, and the table overflow the other side.

[image]

I know there is a method using `\thead`, but I could not figure out and I do not want to change for format `\begin{tabular}{lll}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,epsfig,times}

\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} 
\usepackage{tabulary,siunitx} 

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
\multirow{2.4}{*}{\textbf{Selecting Panel}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Total Item}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
 & {\textbf{Item 1}} & {\textbf{Item 2}} \\
     \midrule
    Stick & Stick Stick Stick & Stick Stick Stick Stick \\
        Stick & Stick Stick Stick & Stick Stick Stick Stick \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `\thead` ("table head") or `\thread`?

Comment: @Mico, sorry, is `\thead`

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `\thead` that needs work for resetting its defaults. What you need is a “smashed” header, that TeX will see as not occupying any vertical space.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\smashedhead}[2][]{%
  \smash{#1\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
\smashedhead[\bfseries]{Selecting\\Panel} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Features}}\\ 
\cmidrule{2-3}
& {\textbf{Item 1}} & {\textbf{Item 2}} \\
\midrule
Stick & Stick Stick & Stick Stick \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It work. Can we make the `selecting panel` move a bit lower, it seemed not in the middle

Comment: @aan It should *not* be in the middle. It doesn't refer to what's at its right, does it? The table has a row with the main headers and another row with secondary headers. So “Selecting” should be at the same level as the other main headers; the “Panel” part is attached to it and people will know that it's below just in order to save space (and be grateful for it).

Comment: sorry for my English. I am writing a conference paper and the template is 2 row in a page. Thus, i want to make the `Selecting Panel` in 2 row and middle. Because if 1 row, it will exceed the page column

Comment: @aan Then use a nested tabular inside `\multirow`, adjusting manually the position. I'm not interested in producing tables I consider bad, sorry.