# How to avoid table overflow (overlap)?

Tags: tabularx

This is a follow up questions from
[enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547556/how-to-avoid-table-overflow-overlap-another-side)

I want to make the content of the table to be in 2 row:
[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,epsfig,times}

\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} 
\usepackage{tabulary,siunitx} 

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
\multirow{2.4}{*}{\textbf{Selecting Panel}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Total Item}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
 & {\textbf{Item 1}} & {\textbf{Item 2}} \\
     \midrule
    Stick & Stick Stick Stick & Stick Stick Stick Stick \\
        Stick & Stick Stick Stick & Stick Stick Stick Stick \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated but don't use `epsfig` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you  load `makecell`, use `\multirowthead` to use a two-lined column head.

*Unrelated*: `times` is obsolete, so I replaced it with `newtx` , based on the`times` clone  `TeX Gyre Termes`.  The  `epsfig` package  also is obsolete, as you can get its functionalities with `graphicx`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, newtxtext, newtxmath}

\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption}
\usepackage{tabulary,siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\theadalign}{lc}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
\multirowthead{2.84}{Selecting\\ Panel} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Total Item}}\\
     \cmidrule{2-3}
 & {\textbf{Item 1}} & {\textbf{Item 2}} \\
     \midrule
    Stick & Stick Stick Stick & Stick Stick Stick Stick \\
        Stick & Stick Stick Stick & Stick Stick Stick Stick \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry for late reply. Thanks, it works